# How to move Slider in an IFRAME that doesn't have a name/id?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, iframe

[image]
I am unable to move the slider in an IFRAME section: https://jqueryui.com/slider/

The IFRAME doesn't have a name or id on this page.

Code:

```
public class MovingSlider {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/slider/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        driver.switchTo().frame(1);
        WebElement slider = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'slider']/span"));
        new Actions(driver).dragAndDropBy(slider, 400,0).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out the [Slider example source](https://jqueryui.com/slider/) by selecting the **view source** link below the example. Then...select the [API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/) link at the very bottom of that.

Comment: While the link to the page is nice, please add the relevant HTML from the page. If the link goes dead or the content on the page changes, this question will be useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is dom contains only one frame whose index is "0" and you tried to switch to index "1" frame which actually didn't exist.

Following is the code snippet that works for you.

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/slider/");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
Integer size = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size();
System.out.println("Total iFrame is " + size);
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
WebElement slider = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'slider']/span"));
// WebElement slider = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#slider > span"));
new Actions(driver).dragAndDropBy(slider, 400, 0).build().perform();
```